# Access certain columns in d3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm importing data from a csv file, which contains a column of strings and a column of numbers. I want choose the second column so I can use it for a plot, but I don't know how. I have the following code so far, which imports the data and parses it, but I don't know what to do next.

```
d3.csv("food.csv", function(data) {
            return {
                Food : data.Food,
                Deliciousness : +data.Deliciousness
            };
        });
```

And my csv file contains:

```
Food,Deliciousness
Apples,9
Green Beans,5
Egg Salad Sandwich,4
Cookies,10
Liver,0.2
Burrito,7
```

Comment: It looks like you have those column titles in the first line of your csv file, so no need to rebuild the object in the body of your function. The callback function is invoked once the file is fully parsed, and is meant for cleaning up the data and initiating the drawing step. Search for examples of charts similar to what you want to do on bl.ocks.org -- like this one... https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: There are also many pre-built libraries that will take your data and render D3 graphs (chartjs, plotly, highcharts, nvd3, dygraph, just to name a few). But if you really want to learn HOW they work with D3, so you can design your own solutions, here is a great place to start: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make a wild assumption here, but what I think you're asking for is to have an array of numbers that contains all of the numbers from the right-hand column of your CSV file. If so, then this code should give you what you need:

```js
d3.csv(
  "food.csv", 
  (data) => ({
    Food: data.Food,
    Deliciousness: +data.Deliciousness
  }),
  (err, rows) => {
    const foodArray = rows.map((val) => val.Food);
    const deliciousnessArray = rows.map((val) => val.Deliciousness);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```